# Spurious type error with variadic template and tuple in CLion?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, clion

I am trying to make a constructor that takes a map of type enum (key) and tuple (value). The types in the tuple are not known. Therefore i make a variadic template (parameter pack):

```
template <typename ...T> Entity(map<TYPE, tuple<T...>>)  {}
```

And my main:

```
map<TYPE, tuple<int,char>> theMap;
Entity* e = new Entity(theMap);
```

The issue is that my IDE complains:

```
Parameter type mismatch: Class map<TYPE, tuple<int,char> is not compatible with class 'map<TYPE,tuple<int,char,int,char>>'
```

So somehow i get duplicates of every type in the tuple of the constructor. This compiles with no errors by the way but its just very annoying.

Complete example of my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;
enum TYPE {DRAWABLE, COLLIDABLE, MOVABLE};

class Entity {
private:
public:
    template <typename ...T> Entity(map<TYPE, tuple<T...>>)  {}
};

int main() {
    map<TYPE, tuple<int,char>> theMap;
    Entity* e = new Entity(theMap);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: THE PROOF]

How come the tuple in the constructor is created with duplicate types? (int, char, int, char) when i only specified (int,char). Have I misinterpreted how the template works or is it just a bug with the IDE?

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: Does it really say "*missmatch*"?

Comment: @melpomene what do you mean? this is basicaly the only code i have. But if it does any difference i will post my whole "program". Yes it says that.

Comment: Why are you voting down?

Comment: You forgot to `#include <tuple`.

Comment: What IDE is this?

Comment: @Bonbin: Probably because you're not copy/pasting your compiler output, but rather retyping something by hand that may contain further invented errors that obscure the problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB i removed it before because it sayd "unused import statement"

Comment: @KerrekSB my compiler does not give me any output, as i said the code compiles perfectly. I just get a red underscore and when i hover over it displays the msgs.

Comment: "*This compiles with no errors*" ... "*The issue is that my IDE complains*". OK, so your IDE is broken. What exactly do you want from us?

Comment: I don't care if the code "compiles perfectly"; without the inclusion of the required headers, it's broken code.

Comment: (It looks like what the IDE *should* have said is that the header `<string>` is unused. This is extremely fishy.)

Comment: @melpomene if you think thats what causes then i dont think you can help me

Comment: @KerrekSB i reincluded tuple and added a picture that proves my problem, i am not lying about the error msg. I was thinking the parameter package might have unpacked itself twice and therefore gives a warning. I suspect it compiles because a tuple<int, char, int, char> is indeed compatible with a tuple<int, char> its just my IDE that thinks its a problem. Do you know how to design the template so that it only creates a tuple of  one int and one char?

Comment: @melpomene but you are saying that the variadic template in my example should not result in a tuple of duplicate types? (int, char, int, char) in this case?

Comment: @Bonbin Why did you lie to us? The message does not say "*missmatch*".

Comment: @melpomene are you having a bad day? (edited that spelling error)

Comment: @Bonbin that IDE warning is clearly wrong, but that happens a lot with IDE's, only compilation tells if that was really an error. BTW why not give the map itself as the template argument? I mean `template <typename T> Entity(const T&)`

Comment: @A.S.H Okay, thanks for the tip that constructor was better looking.

Comment: CLion is pretty good as C++ IDE, but not well-polished by now. You can create a bug report here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com